# Iterating through response data to create google map objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, google-maps

I have data like this:

```
 "meta":{"About thisdata"}, "objects": [{"beat": "1614", "block": "081XX W HIGGINS RD", "case_number": "JA100466", "classification": "/api/1.0-beta3/crimeclassification/83/", "community_area": "/api/1.0-beta3/communityarea/10/", "community_name": "Norwood Park", "community_number": 10, "community_slug": "norwood-park", "crime_date": "2016-12-30T18:00:00", "description": "$500 AND UNDER", "domestic": false, "fbi_code": "06", "id": "10801504", "iucr": "0820", "latitude": 41.985421498, "location_description": "STREET", "longitude": -87.829756604, "primary_type": "THEFT", "ward": 41, "year": 2016},
```

In total this will have 500 objects under "objects"

I am trying to create 500 of these: `new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)`

to put in an array like this:

```
function getPoints() {
        return [
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688)

         ]
}
```

to be returned here:

```
function initMap () {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 41.881, lng: -87.629 },
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: makeMarkers(), <-- Here
    map: map
  });
}
```

The code I have tried look like this:

```
var makeMarkers = function () {
  var result = [];
  var lat, lng = [];
  resp.objects.forEach(function(objects) { 
  lat.objects.latitude;
  lng = objects.longitude;
  return [new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)]
})
}
```

but instead of returning an array of new objects, it returns 500 new arrays with one google object because it's inside the forEach. I'm not sure how to get what I'm looking for. I struggle a fair amount with scopes and iterating through data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the `resp` object is the object at the top of your post. First of all, you'll want to use `map` on the array to actually get an array back.

**Map**

Map works similar to forEach since it acts on every element in the array. The difference is that within the callback to `map` you return an updated element.

Ex:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (element) {
  return element * 2
}
```

The above with return an array as follows: `[2, 4, 6, 8]`.
Note the return within the callback method.

**For your case**

You want to get the array of `objects` from your `resp` and `map` each of those elements to the Google Maps object (i.e. `google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)`)

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, the following should work. I'd suggest playing around with more simple examples of `map` (also `filter`,`forEach`, and `reduce` (`foldr` in some languages) are good to know).

```
var makeMarkers = function () {
  var result = [];
  var lat, lng = [];
  return resp.objects.map(function(element) {
    lat = element.latitude;
    lng = element.longitude;
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  })
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I explained myself well enough. I'll be more concise. I'm trying to pull out all of the Lat and Lng from the 500 objects and make an array of 500 instances of `new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude)` like googe's documentation here --> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Comment: In that case, the above should do it. For each element of the `objects` array, the lat/lng are pulled out and a new Google Maps object is created. They are all mapped into an array and returned.

Comment: Nvm I didn't see what you did there.

Comment: You can read about map a little more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Good luck!